# Making an animation follow a path in a appointed time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I would like to make a image go through a path. So far I have found tutorials that teach how to do this.
However I wish that this same image go through this path in a given time such as two minutes.

My intention is to make a path where an image goes from point A to B in 2 minutes and then from B to C in 3 minutes.

Someone would have some indication / help for me?

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out GreenSock TweenMax.https://greensock.com/tweenmax-as

The thing that you're looking for is called bezier (scroll down to the Plugin Explorer)

After importing the library you can animate your display object like that:

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;

TweenMax.to(mc, 2*60, {bezier:{autoRotate:true, values:[{x:201, y:314}, {x:190, y:234}, {x:313, y:317}]}, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
```

Comment: Thank for your help, I will try to make this Library work with multiple stops.